# Show that the semigroup corresponding to the Yosida approximation is contractive

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ be a closed densely-defined linear operator on a $\mathbb R$-Banach space $E$ such that $(0,\infty)$ is contained in the resolvent set $\rho(A)$ of $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ and $$\left\|\lambda R_\lambda(A)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}\le1\;\;\;\text{for all }\lambda>0\tag1,$$ where $$R_\lambda(A):=B_\lambda^{-1}$$ with $$B_\lambda:=\lambda\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal D(A)}-A$$ for $\lambda\in\rho(A)$. Now, let $$A_n:=nAR_n(A)=n^2R_n(A)-n\operatorname{id}_E$$ and $$T_n(t):=e^{tA_n}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

> How can we show that $$\left\|T(t)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}\le 1?\tag2$$

I've seen a proof claiming that $$\left\|T(t)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}\le e^{-nt}e^{\left\|n^2R_n(A)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}t}\tag3\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N,$$ but how do we obtain this? Clearly, $$\left\|e^{tB}\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}\le e^{t\left\|B\right\|_{\mathfrak L(B)}}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag4$$ for all $B\in\mathfrak L(E)$, but I don't get why we can pull out the $e^{-nt}$ in $(3)$.

Comment: $e^{A+B}=e^{A}e^{B}$ if $A$ and $B$ commute. In your case, $-nI$ and $n^2 R_n(A)$ commute.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: What is $A_1$? $I-A$ or $A(I-A)^{-1}$?

Comment: A power series argument works the same for real or complex numbers $A,B$ as it does for bounded commuting operators. In either case, $e^{A+B}=e^{A}e^{B}$.

Comment: @Pedro $A_1=\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal D(A)}-A$. Why do you think it could be something else?

Comment: Because $A_n:=nAR_n(A)=n^2R_n(A)-n\operatorname{id}_E$.

Comment: @Pedro Sorry, mistakenly defined the same symbol twice.

Answer (score 1):

In the Hille-Yosida Theorem, it is assumed that $(\lambda I-A)$ is invertible for all $\lambda > 0$, and that $\|\lambda (\lambda I-A)^{-1}\| \le 1$ for all $\lambda > 0$. Therefore, if $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ and $\lambda > 0$,
\begin{align}
   \lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x&=(\lambda I-A)(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x+(\lambda I-A)^{-1}Ax \\
        &= x+(\lambda I-A)^{-1}Ax \\
   \|\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x-x\| &\le \frac{1}{\lambda}\|Ax\|.
\end{align}
Therefore $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x=x$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. Using the density of the domain of $A$ and the resolvent estimate $\|\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\|$, it follows that
$$
        \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x=x,\;\; \forall x\in X.
$$
Therefore,
$$
      \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda (\lambda I-A)^{-1}Ax=Ax,\;\;x\in\mathcal{D}(A) \\
     \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty} \lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\{(A-\lambda I)x+\lambda I\}x=Ax \\
    \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\{-\lambda+\lambda^2(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\}x=Ax.
$$
The semigroup for $A$ can be defined as
\begin{align}
      T(t)x & = \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left[t\{-\lambda+\lambda^2(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\}\right]x
\end{align}
For any $x\in X$ and $\lambda > 0$,
$$
     \|\exp\left[t\{-\lambda+\lambda^2(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\}\right]x\| \\
    \le e^{-t\lambda} \exp\left[t\lambda\|\lambda(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\|\right]\|x\| \\
    \le e^{-t\lambda} e^{t\lambda}\|x\|= \|x\|.
$$
Therefore $\|T(t)\| \le 1$ for all $t \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

> *How can we show $(2)$?*

Following [Pazy's argument](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=DQvpBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=%22is+a+bounded+linear+operator+and+thus+is+the+infinitesimal+generator+of+a+uniformly+continuous+semigroup%22&source=bl&ots=jOVRhiOwL1&sig=1O7gwbS7kggVqa0emWyu_drogP8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR_Kqj1cfeAhXBgZAKHRh0CZwQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20bounded%20linear%20operator%20and%20thus%20is%20the%20infinitesimal%20generator%20of%20a%20uniformly%20continuous%20semigroup%22&f=false) (which seems to be the standard one, where $T(t)$ is defined by $T(t)x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{e}^{t A_n}x$), it is enough to show that
$$\|\mathrm{e}^{t A_n}\|_\mathcal{L}\leq 1,\quad\forall\  n\in\mathbb N.$$

For this, note that
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\|\mathrm{e}^{t A_n}\|_\mathcal{L}
&= \|\mathrm{e}^{tn^2(n-A)^{-1}}\mathrm{e}^{-tn I}\|_{\mathcal{L}}
= \|\mathrm{e}^{tn^2(n-A)^{-1}}\mathrm{e}^{-tn }I\|_{\mathcal{L}}
=\mathrm{e}^{-tn}\|\mathrm{e}^{tn^2(n-A)^{-1}}\|_{\mathcal{L}}\\
&\leq\mathrm{e}^{-tn}\mathrm{e}^{tn^2\|(n-A)^{-1}\|_\mathcal{L}}\leq \mathrm{e}^{-tn}\mathrm{e}^{tn}=1.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}